# firebase rules for children but not parent

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase and want to allow writing on a child but not on parent.

I have a collection that is called guests.
Users can set data to it using their userId by writing data to: guests/userId
I want to prevent a user to write data on guests: /guests.

These are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "guests": {
       ".write": "newData.exists()",
    }
  }
}
```

With the rules above, user can run both commands:

```
guests.child(userId).set(profileData);
guests.set(profileData);
```

I want to make a rule that prevent him to run the second line: `guests.set(profileData);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WildCard for user id:

```
"rules": {
  ".read": false,
  ".write": false,
  "guests": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "$user_id": {
      ".write": "newData.exists()",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `".read": false,` and `".write": false,` under `guest` are not needed, since those are already inherited from the root.